# How do I create mean three way table in srvyr

Tags: survey

I want to create table using srvyr package

| Residence | State A | State B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Urban | mean age | mean age |
| Rural | mean age | mean age |

But not able get the desired result in tabular from.
I tried group by function and across function and survey_mean. I do not want to use any of the summary table packages.
Requesting for guidance